# How can i approve a task assigned from sharepoint 2013 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, task-assignment

I am receiving email notifications but how should i approve or reject a task through it?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a link in the email (if it was developed such a way) that will redirect you to the SharePoint site to approve/reject tasks.

Comment: It does redirect me to the sharepoint site that shows the item that was created in the list but I do no see any approve or reject option there.

Answer (score 1):

When you are redirected to the list item page, you need to click “Edit Item” in the ribbon.

[image]

Then it will redirect to the edit form page with the “Approved/Rejected” options under the columns.

[image]